# Drawing CAShapeLayer with a big CGPath

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics, calayer, cashapelayer

I am creating a vector based drawing app, and being truly vector based I need to have a "limitless" canvas. So I have created the following structure:

```
UIVIew (canvas view)
  |
  CALayer (canvas container)
    |
    CAShapeLayer (the drawn shapes)
    ...
```

Each shape that has been drawn by the user is a CAShapeLayer with a CGPath assigned to it.
When the user zooms out the container (say the container has a size of about 10000x10000 points) and draws a new shape I get the points in scale of 1 and than assign a scale transform to the new CAShapeLayer (that`s the only way I found that works).

The problem is that in my app I can draw a connection between two objects, so I use a CAShapeLayer to draw the connection but when zoomed out (say the distance between two shapes is about 5000pts) I draw a line with two points which distance is about 5000pts as well. Doing that I think the springboard is restarted.
I've read that CAShapeLayer caches only the pixels of the drawn path and maybe that's my problem.
So I ask for your help guys because I ran out of ideas.
Is there a different approach to doing these huge shapes drawing and easily operate with them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is probably a solution if you are using tiled layers for connections.  I am guessing, that the shape layer is busting the backing store, and by drawing things in a tiled fashion, the things you keep are fewer.